# Solving T(n) = 2*T(n-1)+4 witht the Master Theorem

Tags: time-complexity, master-theorem

I am wondering if there is a way to solve a recurrence time function with the master theorem if no $b$ exists. Like in this case.
$$ T(n) = 2\times T(n-1)+4$$

Comment: No b exists and b=0 are different things.

Comment: The master theorem is useful for many recurrences, but it isn't the correct tool for *all* of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By expansion you can see it is $T(n) = \Theta(2^n)$ (suppose $T(1) = 1$):

$$
T(n) = 2T(n-1) +4 = 2(2T(n-2)+4) + 4 = 2^2T(n-2) + 2\times 4 + 4 = \ldots =
$$

$$
2^{n-1}T(1) + 2^{n-2}4 + \cdots + 4 = 4\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}2^i\right) = 4(2^n - 1)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $S(n) = T(n)/2^n$. Then
$$
S(n) = S(n-1) + \frac{4}{2^n}.
$$
Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4}{2^n}$ converges, we see that $S(n) = \Theta(1)$, and so $T(n) = \Theta(2^n)$.